# Spring XD Custom Module with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-xd

What is the proper way to create a Spring XD module which will make use of additional Boot autoconfigs? I have a module which is packaged with the additional boot libraries not already provided by XD. However, I am not seeing the Autoconfig's being processed.

For reference, I am trying to create an XD module which depends on spring-cloud-starter-eureka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be user error. Apparently when combining XML config and JavaConfig in a module, the JavaConfig is ignored.